# algorithm to join two time serial data

Tags: java, sql

I have two time serial data but I want to combine them into one. New alarm value will only be 1 when both alarms are 1 at same time.
Time..........**Alarm01**
01:01:01    .....**0**
01:01:**05**    .....**1**
01:01:**07**    .....**0**
01:01:**20**    .....**1**

Time        ........**Alarm02**
01:01:01    .....**0**
01:01:**06**    .....**1**
01:01:**08**    .....**0**
01:01:**25**    .....**1**

Expected Result is:
Time        ........**Alarm**
01:01:01    .....**0**
01:01:**06**    .....**1**
01:01:**07**    .....**0**
01:01:**25**    .....**1**
"." is for each reading only. it can be ignored.
kindly please share with me any good algorithm either in Java or SQL. My current implementation is to loop both serial but I'm looking for any mature algorithm which I may not know.

Comment: Do you want to join the two lists ? or just compare them and flag identical ones with 1 ? Joining can be as simple as using `Set`

Comment: I only want to compare them and flag identical ones with 1. @c0der

Comment: No need to loop, use [ArrayList.contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object))

Comment: @c0der it will give him cubic time complexity

Comment: If you have any complexity requests or limitation, put it in the question

Answer (score 0):

You can do this efficiently without using any good algorithm, you alarm time is incremental so if your first element from first list does not match with your first element from second list then break the loop and go to the third alarm list.

As you are looking for a mature algorithm:You can use this one also without even comparing all  alarms:

Create an array of linkedlist, compute some hashvalue for each alarm and add it to the linkedlist corresponding to that array index: Example

```
array[hashValue].add(alarm)
```

Within the linkedlist you have to compare few alarms. You can do this by only compparing seconds if you make a good hashfunction.If you have already an alarm with same data then simply increment the counter within the linkedlist otherwise add it to head or tail as you prefer.